# How to determine where object is dragged from?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a user input page where users can drag objects (text boxes) into other draggable areas. These correspond to inputs on a form.

But I need to track where the items are moved FROM each time they're dragged/dropped. I have not been able to find a method to do this. Is there a method/attribute in JS for the event to figure out where (which draggable area ID/Name) a user initiated the drag FROM?

For example, in the **drop** function below I can find where it's being dropped TO, using "ev.target.id". Is there an equivalent function for tracking where (which div/input box name or id) that item originally was located during the operation?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        var _target = $("#" + ev.target.id);
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        if ($(_target).hasClass("noDrop")) {
            console.log("no transfer");
            ev.preventDefault();
        } else {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log("transfer success");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple variable that you declare on load, then overwrite it every time in the drag/event handler function. Then you can access that variable in the drop function etc..

```
let dragSource;

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    dragSource = ev.target;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the proposed solution. But, with that dragSource variable, how would I extract the name or id of the div where it was pulled from? For instance, if I access: "dragSource.id" from the drop function (after setting in the drag function) it gives me the id of the item being dragged, not the location where it's from.

Comment: @Thomas, for something like that you are going to need to post more code than you have. It doesn't show with the HTML looks like nor does it show the event handlers themselves

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'll have to distill the code a bit to give an example and then will post an update here.